# emit data on disconnect event from client to server on node

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I couldnt send the data from the client to server on disconnect event

//clients side

```
var gname = "asd";
    socket.emit('disconnect',gname);
```

//server side

```
    socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
console.log(data);

        var i = connect_clients.indexOf(data);
        if(i != -1) {
            connect_clients.splice(i, 1);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to, because the socket was disconnected from server. The event on server fires when the server detects disconnect (not magically by a fraction before that) and the "bridge" between client and server is **already** closed/interrupted/whatever - no connectivity means no data interchange.

You have two options on how to do something with disconnected client:

1. use database or local variables to store some user information by 'socket.id' (for example track down online users). When you get `disconnect` event on server you can see socket's id what get disconnected. Use this `id` to do needed stuff like decrease online users count and broadcast this to others.
2. (rather bad solution) wait for `reconnect` event on client and send the data from there when the connection will be reestablished. Of course if the server will remains down the data probably will be lost.

If you need to perform some simple server side stuff, solution 1 may work just fine, but if you have something complex, like unsaved form data, you will have to come up with some sort of saving the data in `localStorage`, for example, and sync it back upon `reconnect`.

Comment: i coudlnt make it reconect otherwise it would have solved my problem though

Comment: then probably storing data in `localStorage` and sending it back upon next connect would be appropriate solution in this case.

Comment: you mean in socket everything matters on it socket id and everything i would save under socket id of the client and take data connection as per the wish

Comment: Sorry, it is very hard for me to understand you. Could you please try to rephrase your comment above? Thank you

Comment: hello you mean server localstorage or clients?

Comment: Client side. [More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)